# Grail command objects instance validation?

Tags: validation, grails, command-objects

Let's say I have a command-object containing seven fields(String monday, String tuesday, ..) and I need to validate it just to check if at least one of them exists.

Because of working with Grails 1.3.7 I tried to use instance validation with extended-validation-plugin(not rich-domain) but I couldn't make it work. Basically, it does not recognise non-field validator inside of static constraints block.

static constraints = {
        availabilitySelected(validator: {
            ...
        })
        ...

and I get:

*Exception Message: No such property: availabilitySelected*

Is there any other smart way to do it? I just do not want to add validator for every single field in my command object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object being validated via the two / three parameter form of a custom validator.

```
myField(validator: { val, obj, errors -> if( obj.blah.empty && obj.blah.empty ) { errors.reject( ... ) } )
```

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Constraints/validator.html

Comment: Thanks, I moved the validation to one of the fields('monday')  I just thought there is a nicer way to do it. For example in my tests I have to check for 'monday' FieldError which is actually not that descriptive as when nothing has been selected the problem is with the whole instance of command object not with 'monday' field.

Comment: No, just pass in the errors object and do a errors.reject instead of errors.rejectvalue - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject(java.lang.String)